# id function not working if i user jQuery load page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function new_exp() { $("#quickIndexTab").load("/pages/expenditure/new_exp.php");  }
</script>

<a href="#"    onclick="javascript:new_exp()" >List</a>

<div id="quickIndexTab"></div>
```

**new_exp.php**

```
 <label>Date picker</label>
 <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="" />
```

When refresh new_exp.php the datepicker not working and id is also not working.

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery is loaded? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: There is no error... if load the code directly its running...

Comment: What do you mean by "load the code directly"?

Comment: If i use <label>Date picker</label>
 <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="" /> this code directly to index page its running...

Comment: Leave out the `javascript:` part in your `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. no need for javascript pseudo protocol/label
2. return false
3. if you have jQuery, use it to assign the script
4. if you want a datepicker to work after load, you need to assign it in the callback

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#pageLink").on("click",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // cancel link
     $("#quickIndexTab").load(this.href,function(){
       $("#datepicker").datePicker(); 
     }); 
  });
});
</script>
<a id="pageLink" href="/pages/expenditure/new_exp.php">Click</a>
```